# Neo4j 2.2.2 inconsistency problems

Tags: neo4j

I did an explicit upgrade of a Neo4j database from 2.1.6 to 2.2.2 a couple of days ago. Everything seemed fine at first but yesterday I started to get a lot of:

```
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Neo4jClient.NeoException: EntityNotFoundException: Relationship with id 93669
```

and

```
enter codException: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Neo4jClient.NeoException: RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.InvalidRecordException: DynamicRecord Not in use, blockId[32134]e here
```

errors in my log. Doing a full backup on my master db gives me 12 inconsistency errors:

```
2015-06-09 05:30:56.273+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: The property chain contains multiple properties that have the same property key id, which means that the entity has at least one duplicate property.
Node[5373,used=true,group=53,prop=105814,labels=Inline(0x1000000000:[0]),light]
```

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Is this an enterprise cluster? Are you writing to slaves by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is an enterprise cluster of 1 master and 2 slaves. No not that I know, I am using the default settings which I suppose only lets the master write?

Comment: I'd say in this case, please contact Neo4j's support and provide all the logs, so that they can investigate how your database got into this state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got help from the awesome Neo4j support team:

"We figured it out and will fix it in the next release. Until then can you run either only single instance, or write/read ONLY from/to MASTER or ONLY SLAVES. It is an issue with stale caches of the master."